# Spring WebApplicationInitializer and Jetty 8.x

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, jetty

I am trying to deploy an app in Jetty using Maven:

I have the plugin configured as follows:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>8.0.4.v20111024</version>
</plugin>
```

And I have a WebApplicationContextInitializer, I have cut it down to a simple form for here:

```
AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();

// Register and map the main dispatcher servlet
ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet("appServlet", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherContext));
dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(2);
dispatcher.addMapping("/site/*");
```

When I run jetty:run from within Spring Tool Suite I cannot access my servlet. The startup logs are:

```
    [INFO] Configuring Jetty for project: Test
    [INFO] webAppSourceDirectory C:\Users\Alex\Documents\spring\Test\src\main\webapp does not exist. Defaulting to C:\Users\Alex\Documents\spring\Test\src\main\webapp
    [INFO] Reload Mechanic: automatic
    [INFO] Classes = C:\Users\Alex\Documents\spring\Test\target\classes
    [INFO] Context path = /
    [INFO] Tmp directory = C:\Users\Alex\Documents\spring\Test\target\tmp
    [INFO] Web defaults = org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/webdefault.xml
    [INFO] Web overrides =  none
    [INFO] web.xml file = null
    [INFO] Webapp directory = C:\Users\Alex\Documents\spring\Test\src\main\webapp
    2012-02-06 21:22:38.048:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-8.0.4.v20111024
    2012-02-06 21:22:38.807:INFO:oejpw.PlusConfiguration:No Transaction manager found - if your webapp requires one, please configure one.
    2012-02-06 21:22:41.828:INFO:/:Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath: [org.test.application.config.TestWebApplicationInitializer@f946f9]
    2012-02-06 21:22:41.965:INFO:/:Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'appServlet'
    INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'appServlet': initialization started
    INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'appServlet-servlet': startup date [Mon Feb 06 21:22:41 GMT 2012]; root of context hierarchy
    INFO : org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Named' annotation found and supported for component scanning
    INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
    INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@18b24cb: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor#0]; root of factory hierarchy
    INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'appServlet': initialization completed in 235 ms
    2012-02-06 21:22:42.344:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:started o.m.j.p.JettyWebAppContext{/,file:/C:/Users/Alex/Documents/spring/Test/src/main/webapp/},file:/C:/Users/Alex/Documents/spring/Test/src/main/webapp/
    2012-02-06 21:22:42.344:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:started o.m.j.p.JettyWebAppContext{/,file:/C:/Users/Alex/Documents/spring/Test/src/main/webapp/},file:/C:/Users/Alex/Documents/spring/Test/src/main/webapp/
    2012-02-06 21:22:42.345:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:started o.m.j.p.JettyWebAppContext{/,file:/C:/Users/Alex/Documents/spring/Test/src/main/webapp/},file:/C:/Users/Alex/Documents/spring/Test/src/main/webapp/
    2012-02-06 2012-02-06 21:22:42.352:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080 STARTING
    [INFO] Started Jetty Server
```

If then navigate to http://localhost:8080/ I get the default Jetty page with no contexts listed.

I have tried copying webdefaults.xml into my project as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8066943/spring-3-1-servlet-3-code-based-configuration-using-the-jetty-maven-plugin) but this didn't fix the issue. It just removed the default servlet page.

This deploys correctly in Tomcat so I suspect an issue in the maven-jetty-plugin.

Does anyone have any experience in this area?

Edit:

So I can confirm that if I change the Jetty config so that the app is deployed under context /application and then navigate to http://localhost:8080/application/site/ I get a 404.

However, the dispatcher servlet has logged:

```
No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/application/site/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'
```

This suggests that there is an issue with my Controller mappings correct?

The startup logs show this mapping is registered:

```
Mapped "{[/],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String org.test.application.controller.HomeController.catchAll()
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Sorry for stupid question, but you have added the mapping to `/site`, so I would expect the site to be available on `http://localhost:8080/site/`, no?

Comment: I would have expected the same. But that's not the case.

Comment: Have added some more details.

Comment: Why do you go to `http://localhost:8080/application/site/`? You have deployed you application to root context (see `Context path = /` from your log), so the URL should be `http://localhost:8080/site/`. Can you try it? If it does no help, then increase the logging to TRACE level and grep the log.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I think I worked it out. The servlet was mapped correctly but the Controllers weren't. They were in the root context and should have been in the dispatcher context.

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that I was running into this issue: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?122876-Root-Application-Context-loading-after-Dispatcher-Context

Comment: If you solved your issue, please create an answer with the solution and mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the new Jetty plugin is using root "/" as root context of the web application, the old one was as written below:

> contextPath Optional. The context path for your webapp. By default,
>   this is set to the  from the project's pom.xml. You can
>   override it and set it to anything you like here.